# Rowcolors and horizontal lines do not mix

Tags: tables, beamer, rowcolor

Using rowcolors causes the horizontal and vertical lines in my table to behave strangely
. The second horizontal line after the first row is not visible, and the vertical line dissappears in the second row. Is there a way around this?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Famous Composers}
\begin{center}
    %\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray} %-- this indicates the change in odd and pair rows
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}\hline
    a & b \\\hline\hline
    c & d \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see 4 horizontal lines and 6 vertical ones. Zoom in and they will be there. This is most probably the typical pdf-viewer problem with lines

Comment: sorry it's just a feature of the way colouring works, It's a commonly asked question so I closed as duplicate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see. I never thought it would be an issue connected with Adobe Reader, so I didn't find the duplicate question.